# Bower - Change directory name when package is installed

Tags: bower

When I install the following package from this git url, it creates a directory **/flyLabel.js**

bower install **https://github.com/space150/flyLabel.js.git**

The fact the directory has a dot in its name is causing issues elsewhere when I am trying to include it.

**Question**
Is there a way to change the name of the directory Bower is going to create when it installs the package?